# Binomial distribution as sum of Bernoulli distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

Let's give a generic discrete probability space $(\Omega,P)$ where $|\Omega| \le \aleph_0$.

A random variable $X\colon \Omega \to \{0,\dots,n\}$ is a Binomial one if, by definition, $p_X(k):=P(X=k)=\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$ where $k \in \{0,\dots,n\}$ and $p \in [0,1]$ (**Is this a correct definition? Is there a more general one?**).

I know that if we have $X_1,\dots,X_n\colon\Omega \to \{0,1\}$ independent Bernoulli random variables, then $X:=X_1+\dots+X_n\colon \Omega \to \{0,\dots,n\}$ is a Binomial random variable.

**I'm wondering if the converse holds. Namely, if $X\colon \Omega \to \{0,\dots,n\}$ is a Binomial random variable, then can it be written as the sum of independent Bernoulli random variables?**

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is no.

Consider the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$, where $\Omega = \{0,\ldots,n\}$, $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ and $\mathbb{P}: \mathcal{F} \to [0,1]$ defined as $\mathbb{P}(A) = \sum\limits_{i \in A} \binom ni p^i(1-p)^{n-i}$ for every $A \in \mathcal{F}$.

Consider now $X: \Omega \to \{0,\ldots, n\}$ as $X(i)=i$ (the identity function).

The distribution of $X$ is clearly binomial.

Suppose now that $X = X_1 + \ldots + X_n$ with $X_i$ iid with law Bernoulli of parameter $p$, all defined on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$.

This would mean that there is $A \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $\mathbb{P}(A) = p$.

And this must be true for every $p \in (0,1)$.

Consider the map $F: (0,1) \to \mathcal{P}(\{0,\ldots,n\})$ that for a given $p$ returns such a set $A$. Since the domain is infinite and the codomain is finite there must be a given $A \subseteq \{0,\ldots,n\}$ such that for infinite many $p$ we have $$\sum\limits_{i \in A} \binom ni p^i(1-p)^{n-i} = p$$
Therefore we have $\sum\limits_{i \in A} \binom ni x^i(1-x)^{n-i} = x$ for every real $x$ (polynomial identity).

And now, for example with $n=2$, we obtain that the LHS can be equal to $0,1,x^2,(1-x)^2,2x(1-x),1-x^2,1-(1-x)^2,1-2x(1-x)$, none of which is equal to $x$.

Comment: Thank you so much! So is it still convenient to define a binomial random variable through its distribution $p_X$? Maybe I should define a binomial random variable simply saying that it is the sum of independent Bernoulli variables? Namely, in your opinion, what is the best way to define a binomial random variable?

Comment: It doesn't actually matter. This is because whatever your definition is, there are always a probability space (maybe not the original one) $(\Omega', \mathcal{F}',\mathbb P)$ and $n$ iid variables defined on this new space such that $X_1 + \ldots + X_n$ has the same law, even though it does not coincide